# How to get the "Mom's heart" endings after unlocking "It Lives!"

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

So, I've unlocked It Lives! before getting all the endings for beating Mom's Heart. Is there any way to unlock them now, or is it no longer possible?

Answer (score 3):

No. It Lives does not lock you out of anything that you would get from Mom's Heart, as It Lives is just a more difficult version of Mom's Heart. Defeating It Lives will count for all unlocks that are contingent on beating Mom's Heart.

From [Gamepedia](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/It_Lives):

> It is a stronger version of Mom's Heart that summons bosses alongside regular Womb/Utero enemies.

Lower on the page, it lists all of the Mom's Heart-related unlocks as related unlocks for It Lives, as well.

If you are referring to the endings, as @Pinckerman stated, you should have unlocked the Mom's Heart-related endings before unlocking It Lives. It is not possible to miss any of those endings while still unlocking It Lives.

Comment: I went to the Sheol after getting the devil room, so I skipped that ending for mom's heart. Now that I unlocked It Lives, the chest will not spawn when I defeat it. All unlocks i would normally get I don't have, and I don't have the ending available either.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, after killing Mom's heart 11 times it will be permanently replaced by It Lives. So if you've unlocked It Lives! you should already have the first 11 endings.

From [Endings](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Endings):

> Endings 1 - 11 are available after defeating Mom's Heart. Each time you defeat the boss a new ending is unlocked.

But if you mean that you still miss *Mom's Heart* related achievements, you can unlock them also beating *It Lives!*, as you can see [here](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/It_Lives#Unlockable_Achievements) *It Lives!* has the same bunch of achievements for *Mom's Heart*.

Comment: I will bring up the fact it **is** possible miss the ending videos (which is what I assume the OP is asking about) If you happen to have a door spawn to Sheol on the Mom's Heart Fight and defeat Satan you won't get the ending for Mom's Heart, just Satan.

Comment: @Ramirez In that case, if you don't open the chest but you take the trapdoor to Sheol, I'm not sure if the game will count that Mom's heart kill.

Comment: @pinkerman I am pretty sure it does count as a mom's heart kill since the achievements for killing mom's heart always pop up before you touch the chest, even if you do go down to Sheol.

Comment: @pinckerman Achievements (and item unlocks) based on boss kills happen immediately after beating the boss, not once you open the chest/fall in the trapdoor/fly up the beam of light. You can see evidence of this if you pay attention to when the achievement notification pops up from Steam. However, since the game didn't end when it was expected, it's possible that a certain "ending" might stay locked.

Comment: @MageXy That's true, but secrets/achievements may work in a different way than endings. I've never skipped an ending, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, it was possible to actually [skip an ending](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/692703-the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth/70508863), but I hope they fixed this in 2 years...

Comment: From what I read in a few various forums they did patch it so you do unlock the ending even if you skip it in the game.

Comment: I did skip the chest and went to the Sheol through the devil room. Since I beat Mom's heart, it counted that as a kill. But since I never got the ending, I never got the unlocks for the ending. The notice pops up for all the unlocks after viewing that ending for the first time. If you get the Rubber Cement ending, you unlock rubber cement. If you beat mom's heart and skip to the sheol, you simply won't until you go back and do it again. And there doesn't seem to be a patch (i'm playing it on the N3DS) So i assume i'm boned.

Comment: So apparently, when I beat It Lives! I was able to view the ending I was missing through the Stats menu. I don't know if anyone else has experienced this, but I didn't recieve a note about it. I think I was shown a notice that "Ipecac has appeared in the basement" But I thought that was just for beating It Lives for the first time.

Comment: @Thepicausno Ipecac is unlocked defeating Mom's Heart 6 times, so the message you got was for that. You can watch only one ending per run, but good to know you can now unlock more of them at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Found this out on my own. The game doesn't tell you, but after beating It Lives, you'll recieve a Note that an item has appeared in the basement.  That item is the item you would normally unlock by beating Mom's heart. You can also watch that item's ending through the Stats menu.